# Image capture from camera and save it to string

Tags: iphone

I'm right now taking hardcode image in 1 string located in the Resources folder and then Uploading and downloading through 
processing that string.

My first task is still remaining. 
I want to capture the image by camera and want to save into the Resources folder and also want to give it to 1 string.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the image somewhere, you can use:

```
-(void)chooseImageFromCamera {
    if( ![UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera] ) return;

    UIImagePickerController* picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;

    [currentItem retain];
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}

#pragma mark Image Picker Delegates

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
       didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image 
                 editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo {

    NSData *chosenImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);

        /*  change this to the path of a plist file  */
    NSString *current = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"PlistFile.plist"];
    NSMutableDictionary* plistDict = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:current] autorelease];

    // Do something with the image here.
    [plistDict setObject:chosenImage forKey:@"Photo"];
    [plistDict writeToFile:current atomically:YES];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
    [[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```